# Maven project - Spring MVC Error(s)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am creating Spring MVC project (using Maven), and I receive the following errors when I run it with Tomcat. I create Maven project using spring-mvc-archetype.

Below are the errors:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:         org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springMvcJ    dbcTemplate]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springMvcJdbcTemplate]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at     org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource.getCertificates(AbstractArchiveResource.java:201)
at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2579)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1098)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2148)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2141)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2043)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1995)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1944)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1919)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1880)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1149)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:         org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start     component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Apr 12, 2015 9:57:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is     unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler     ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Apr 12, 2015 9:57:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 12, 2015 9:57:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

And this what is in 'pom.xml':

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>               
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestones</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>springMvcFormHandling</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a tomcat issue.

- Stop the tomcat server.
- Remove all your project first from Tomcat webapp and wptwebapp directories by manually.
- Remove Catalina folder which is inside the work directory.
- Start tomcat with no project deployed.
- If it is started clearly deploy your app and run again.

Comment: It solves the errors. Should I click on the gray check in the answer to accept the answer & it's color will be changed from gray to green?

Comment: @7d0Thanks it is accepted, you are welcome, i am glad to help you.